# How to manually upgrade WSO2 API Manager 4.0.0 to 4.1.0 or 4.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How would you go about manually upgrading API Manager 4.0 to 4.1 or 4.2?

In the past, this used to be a section in the documentation, with instructions on how to upgrade from almost any version, but I can't find that anymore, at least ever since I upgraded to v4 a couple of years ago.

Would it be as simple as replacing the files (minus deployment.toml) and point it to the same DB? Does the DB need to be changed with some script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the past, this used to be a section in the documentation, with
> instructions on how to upgrade from almost any version, but I can't
> find that anymore, at least ever since I upgraded to v4 a couple of
> years ago.

API Manger migration docs are no longer available in the official documentation. You have to contact WSO2 for further assistance regarding migration. Please refer the [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/install-and-setup/upgrading-wso2-api-manager/upgrading-api-manager/).

> Would it be as simple as replacing the files (minus deployment.toml)
> and point it to the same DB? Does the DB need to be changed with some
> script?

It will not be possible to just build the new product and use the same databases as the previous versions since there could be database related changes introduced in the newer versions.

Comment: Ok, it's what I figured, thank you Heshan!